# Criminals and lawsuits

Tags: cryptic-crosswords

[image: blank crossword grid]

**Across**
1. Merely suitable or exactly right (4)
4. Throw dance party after Lent? (8)
10. Happening near Alberto Fujimori's home: Eating shaved ice with the last bit of fruit punch (8)
12. Share load of UN, promoted to lead in African nation by Eritrean extremists after ousting of independent leader (8)
13. Republican lost; in shock for loss of power (6)
14. Meager musician at last getting into singing (5)
15. Canberra and surrounding areas shortly beginning to scrutinise pieces of legislation (4)
17. Mission in 3 down is prepared like in Missouri (5)
20. Join forces and strike back of enemies in sudden charge (4)
21. It travels by Air Koryo, in the end moving from one side of Iberian river to another (5)
22. Company's lead executive starts factories after vacation and signs on staff (5)
23. *Dune* novel is a work of art (4)
27. Going west, Edward and Linus regularly seen with a little German shepherd (5)
28. Exit from capital ended slightly sooner than expected (4)
29. Photons weakly affected by gravity? (5)
31. Last of three duets (composed pieces of music) (6)
34. Large piece of pork hidden in unorthodox Arab emir's palace once (8)
35. Lies spread about religious image showing part of breast, possibly (8)
36. Unhinged male nearly grabbed a perpetrator of violent crime from behind (8)
37. Short skirt confounded boy (4)

**Down**
1. Jay texted you practise sport (4)
2. Stop ground support when lifting weights (4)
3. Place where cowboys are terrible at sex (5)
4. Sparing French ("Gaul") criminal (6)
5. Turn public transport, turn public transport (6)
6. Elaborate brocade shows black and white stripes (7)
7. Ultimately, a Verdi-composed opera (4)
8. Rights for James Cameron's directorial effort initially lacking (5)
9. SoCal city trainee, wanting pie stuffing, carved pumpkin? (7)
11. Joey's home, punching head? That hurts (5)
16. Predator with large body and small brain to utilise less energy reflecting (1-3)
18. Helping of meat of unagi, a food of Eastern Asia (4)
19. Yours truly is supporting African capital, switching sides to get recognition (7)
20. Chinese people stuffing a fig salad and bread (7)
23. Bionic construction of grey metal (6)
24. Feature films by Steven Spielberg, shown during *Idols*, oddly ignored (6)
25. Spin-off clothing for formal occasions? Fashionable (3-2)
26. Civil lawsuit surrounding luxurious residence (5)
28. Very soon, I became a peddler of questionable medicine (5)
30. One way to cross a continent described by latest part of *Travelling Solo* (4)
32. Christian's robot turned around and disappeared (4)
33. Poles acquired electronic console that runs Mario (4, *abbr.*)

Comment: 3d had me raising my eyebrows - nice puzzle!!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The completed grid:

> [image: Solved crossword]

Clue explanations:

> **Across:**
>  1. [Merely suitable] or [exactly right] (4) **JUST** = ddef
>  4. **Throw** dance party after Lent? (8) **FASTBALL** = FAST (Lent) + BALL (dance party)
>  10. Happening near Alberto Fujimori's home: Eating shaved ice with the last bit of fruit **punch** (8) **UPPERCUT** = UP (Happening) + PER[]U containing ((-i)C(-e)) + (-frui)T
>  12. **Share load of** UN, promoted to lead in African nation by Eritrean extremists after ousting of independent leader (8) **UNBURDEN** = [+UN]BUR[-un]D(-i) + E(-ritrea)N
>  13. Republican lost; in shock for **loss of power** (6) **OUTAGE** = OUT(-r)AGE
>  14. **Meager** musician at last getting into singing (5) **SCANT** = SCA(_N)T
>  15. Canberra and surrounding areas shortly beginning to scrutinise **pieces of legislation** (4) **ACTS** = [ACT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Australian_Capital_Territory) + S(-hortly)
>  17. **Mission in 3 down** is prepared like in Missouri (5) **ALAMO** = A LA (‘like’) + MO (Missouri abbrev.)
>  20. **Join forces** and strike back of enemies in sudden charge (4) **ALLY** = (-s)ALLY (where ‘s’ is (-enemie)S)
>  21. **It travels by Air** Koryo, in the end moving from one side of Iberian river to another (5) **ODOUR** = (-kory)O moving from the right end of [DOURO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Douro) to the left end...
>  22. Company's lead executive starts factories after vacation and **signs on staff** (5) **[CLEFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clef)** = C_ L_ E_ + F(-actorie)S
>  23. *Dune* novel is **a work of art** (4) **NUDE** = DUNE*
>  27. Going west, Edward and Linus regularly seen with a little German **shepherd** (5) **GUIDE** = (ED + _I_U_ + G)<
>  28. **Exit from** capital ended slightly sooner than expected (4) **QUIT** = QUIT(-o)
>  29. [Photons] [weakly affected by gravity?] (5) **LIGHT** = ddef
>  31. Last of three duets (composed **pieces of music**) (6) **ETUDES** = (-thre)E + DUETS*
>  34. Large piece of pork hidden in unorthodox Arab **emir's palace once** (8) **[ALHAMBRA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alhambra)** = ARAB* containing L (large) + HAM (piece of pork)
>  35. Lies spread about religious image showing **part of breast, possibly** (8) **SILICONE** = LIES* around ICON (religious image)
>  36. **Unhinged** male nearly grabbed a perpetrator of violent crime from behind (8) **MANIACAL**  MAL(-e) containing A + CAIN
>  37. Short skirt confounded boy (4) **KRIS** = SKIR(-t)*
>
>  **Down:**
>  1. Jay texted you practise **sport** (4) **JUDO** = J + U (texted ‘you’) + DO (‘practise’)
>  2. Stop ground **support when lifting weights** (4) **[SPOT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spotting_(weight_training))** = STOP*
>  3. **Place where cowboys are** terrible at sex (5) **TEXAS** = ATSEX*
>  4. **Sparing** French ("Gaul") criminal (6) **FRUGAL** = FR (French) + GAUL*
>  5. Turn public transport, turn **public transport** (6) **SUBWAY** = ([YAW](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/yaw) + BUS)<
>  6. Elaborate brocade shows **black and white stripes** (7) **BARCODE** = BROCADE*
>  7. Ultimately, a Verdi-composed opera (4) **AIDA** = A + _I + _D + _A &lit!
>  8. **Rights** for James Cameron's directorial effort initially lacking (5) **LIENS** = [(-a)LIENS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliens_(film))
>  9. SoCal city trainee, wanting pie stuffing, **carved pumpkin?** (7) **LANTERN** = LA (SoCal city) + (-i)NTERN (without _I_ from ‘pie stuffing’)
>  11. **Joey's home**, punching head? That hurts (5) **POUCH** = P(-unching) + OUCH (That hurts)
>  16. **Predator with large body and small brain** to utilise less energy reflecting (1-3) **T-REX** = (-e)XERT<
>  18. Helping of meat of unagi, **a food of Eastern Asia** (4) **TOFU** = _T OF U_
>  19. Yours truly is supporting African capital, switching sides to get **recognition** (7) **ACCLAIM** = ACC(r → L)A (African capital, switching sides) + I’M (Yours truly is)
>  20. Chinese people stuffing a fig salad and **bread** (7) **[AFGHANI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Afghani)** = AFIG* containing HAN (Chinese people)
>  23. Bionic construction **of grey metal** (6) **NIOBIC** = BIONIC*
>  24. **Feature** films by Steven Spielberg, shown during *Idols*, oddly ignored (6) **DETAIL** = _D_L_ containing [ET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E.T._the_Extra-Terrestrial) + [AI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A.I._Artificial_Intelligence)
>  25. **Spin-off** clothing for formal occasions? Fashionable (3-2) **TIE-IN** = TIE (clothing for formal occasions) + IN (Fashionable)
>  26. Civil lawsuit surrounding **luxurious residence** (5) **VILLA** = _VIL LA_
>  28. Very soon, I became a **peddler of questionable medicine** (5) **QUACK** = QU(I → A)CK
>  30. **One way to cross a continent** described by latest part of *Travelling Solo* (4) [**GHAN**](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/ghan) = (-travellin)G + HAN (Solo)
>  32. **Christian**'s robot turned around and disappeared (4) **DIOR** = (-and)ROID<
>  33. Poles acquired **electronic console that runs Mario** (4, **abbr.**) **SNES** = S + N + E + S (all ‘poles’ on a compass)

24D is very clever, and I especially love the clue for 3D - highly amusing :)

Comment: Great solve, and great puzzle @jafe!

Comment: Woe, nice solve. I don't even know many of the words in the solution.